# creating split view windows on Ubuntu

Tags: desktop-environments, .desktop, resize

Like on windows i press windows symbol key with left or right arrow to create spilt windows of equal sizes, how do i do that with Ubuntu?
I use Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcut for that is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd>. As for  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Super</kbd> it <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> minimizes/maximizes the windows, so cannot be used to create vertical splits.