# Creating split view window keyboard shortcuts

Tags: 16.04, unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, window-manager

the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd> does not seem to have any function on Ubuntu 16.04 on the contrary to the answer about the Ubuntu 15
[creating split view windows on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678675/creating-split-view-windows-on-ubuntu)
How could I set up a shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd> to make a current window to fill right/left side of the screen?
I have checked the system -> keyboard shortcuts and neither the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd> nor "tile windows" shortcut is present there under any category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
and then open CompizConfig Settings Manager, search for Grid plug-in and change the bindings for Left Maximize and Right Maximize to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd>  accordingly.